# Lock that handles a high-contention, high-frequency situation

Tags: c, multithreading

I am looking for a lock implementation that degrades gracefully in the situation where you have two threads that constantly try to release and re-acquire the same lock, at a very high frequency.

Of course it is clear that in this case the two threads won't significantly progress in parallel.  Theoretically, the best result would be achieved by running the whole thread 1, and then the whole thread 2, without any switching---because switching just creates massive overhead here.  So I am looking for a lock implementation that would handle this situation gracefully by keeping the same thread running for a while before switching, instead of constantly switching.

### Long version of the question

As I would myself be tempted to answer this question by "your program is broken, don't do that", here is some justification about why we end up in this kind of situation.

The lock is a "single global lock", i.e. a very coarse lock.  (It is the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) inside PyPy, but the question is about how to do it in general, say if you have a C program.)

We have the following situation:

- There is constantly contention.  That's expected in this case: the lock is a global lock that needs to be acquired for most threads to progress.  So we expect that a large fraction of them are waiting for the lock.  Only one of these threads can progress.
- The thread that holds the lock might do sometimes bursts of short releases.  A typical example would be if this thread does repeated calls to "something external", e.g. many short writes to a file.  Each of these writes is usually completed very quickly.  The lock still has to be released just in case this external thing turns out to take longer than expected (e.g. if the write actually needs to wait for disk I/O), so that another thread can acquire the lock in this case.

If we use some standard mutex for the lock, then the lock will often switch to another thread as soon as the owner releases the lock.  But the problem is what if the program runs several threads that each wants to do a long burst of short releases.  The program ends up spending most of its time switching the lock between CPUs.

It is much faster to run the same thread for a while before switching, at least as long as the lock is released for very short periods of time.  (E.g. on Linux/pthread a release immediately followed by an acquire will sometimes re-acquire the lock instantly even if there are other waiting threads; but we'd like this result in a large majority of cases, not just sometimes.)

Of course, as soon as the lock is released for a longer period of time, then it becomes a good idea to transfer ownership of the lock to a different thread.

So I'm looking for general ideas about how to do that.  I guess it should exist already somewhere---in a paper, or in some multithreading library?

For reference, PyPy tries to implement something like this by polling: the lock is just a global variable, with synchronized compare-and-swap but no OS calls; one of the waiting threads is given the role of "stealer"; that "stealer" thread wakes up every 100 microseconds to check the variable.  This is not horribly bad (it costs maybe 1-2% of CPU time in addition to the 100% consumed by the running thread).  This actually implements what I'm asking for here, but the problem is that this is a hack that doesn't cleanly support more traditional cases of locks: for example, if thread 1 tries to send a message to thread 2 and wait for the answer, the two thread switches will take in average 100 microseconds each---which is far too much if the message is processed quickly.

Comment: Why wouldn't a spin lock work in your case?

Comment: Not sure what you actually need, but have you thought about `stdatomic.h`?

Comment: Hmm, there's one problem you don't have to solve, it is never going to be "high frequency".  There is no magic button you can push, you must program this different.  Many language runtimes have good support for reactive programming these days.  You'll have to hoof it yourself in C.

Comment: @2501: if you mean something like the last paragraph but with a spin lock instead to poll at a higher frequency than every 100 microseconds, yes, maybe, but I'm not too happy about it because (1) it consumes a second 100% CPU time (2) it needs some careful balancing because if it checks too often, it will succeed in stealing the lock too often...

Comment: @HansPassant: yes, I agree there are other multithreading models, but here we're walking about PyPy whose goal is to provide an implementation of the existing Python language

Comment: This is pretty much the opposite of what people usually look for. In general, high-quality locks have good fairness. Your question boils down to "What kind of lock do I use to savagely starve one of my threads?".

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a lock that has a 'grace period'. Once released, it cannot be grabbed by anybody else *but the original owner* for a short interval. Once the interval passes, any waiter can grab it. Is this correct?

Comment: @EOF: agreed.  The programming model is also "upside-down": the lock is most of the time acquired, and we release it around external calls.  It occurs naturally in this way inside the CPython interpreter too, for example

Comment: @RemusRusanu: yes, that's correct

Comment: @ArminRigo: A while ago I read that some JVM actually automatically coarsens locks if it detects that it is beneficial. I suppose that doesn't really apply here though...

Comment: What OS are you using? I've implemented a similar system under Linux, so I might be able to help. Also, could you talk a bit more about the specifics of the threads because this can influence the best strategy?

Comment: @EOF: Interesting.  But it might be hard to do in practice here because we're trying to coarsen *un*locks, which are around external function calls that we don't control

Comment: I guess if you can compact `<cpuid, timestamp>` into a 64  bit value, then you can implement it with ICX. Not sure if you can get a cheap precise enough timestamp, and I think you might run into issues from time drift between CPUs.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with PyPy and what this lock does, but can you express the semantics as read-write and promote it to a partitioned super-lock (reads only lock their own partition, writes have to lock every partition)? Scales much better...

Comment: @CraigEstey: it's cross-platform (but I'd be happy with a Linux solution to start with).  The thread specifics are vague because the goal is to support all kinds of Python programs that may use threads in different ways.  What I describe in the question is just one particular use case, where it leads to bad performance right now

Comment: @RemusRusanu: no, it's not really possible, because we don't control what the user program in Python is---we are writing an interpreter for Python.  See https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock for an introduction

Comment: @RemusRusanu: in your idea, storing the timestamp is not necessary, as I think you're proposing something similar to the last paragraph of the question, but with the stealer thread polling much more frequently in a spin-loop.  This has the drawback that it will consume another 100% CPU time just for spinning.  Also, we get into fine-tuning territory: check too often, and the lock switches constantly again (but unsure there is a clean solution for that).

Comment: Have a flag that signals to the other threads that a single thread is working in that zone, and send them to sleep immediately for a short time. Once the working thread is done set the flag to false, and the first thread that wakes up, sets the flag to true, and starts working.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, let me describe how we finally implemented it.  I was unsure about it as it still feels like a hack, but it seems to work for PyPy's use case in practice.

We did it as described in the last paragraph of the question, with one addition: the "stealer" thread, which checks some global variable every 100 microseconds, does this by calling `pthread_cond_timedwait` or `WaitForSingleObject` with a regular, system-provided mutex, with a timeout of 100 microseconds.  This gives a "composite lock" with both the global variable and the regular mutex.  The "stealer" will succeed in stealing the "lock" if either it notices a value 0 is the global variable (every 100 microseconds), *or* immediately if the regular mutex is released by another thread.

It's then a matter of choosing how to release the composite lock in a case-by-case basis.  Most external functions (writes to files, etc.) are expected to generally complete quickly, and so we release and re-acquire the composite lock by writing to the global variable.  Only in a few specific function cases---like sleep() or lock_acquire()---we expect the calling thread to often block; around these functions, we release the composite lock by actually releasing the mutex instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem statement, you are asking the kernel scheduler to do an educated guess on whether your userspace application "hot" thread will try to reacquire the lock in the *very* near future, to avoid implicitly preempting it by allowing a "not-so-hot" thread to acquire the mutex.

I wouldn't know how the kernel could do that. The only two things that come to my mind:

- **Do not release mutex** unless hot thread is actually transitioning to idle (application specific condition). In Linux you can use `MONOTONIC_COARSE` to try to reduce the overhead of checking the wall clock to implement some sort of timer.
- **Increase hot thread prio**. This is more of mitigation strategy, in an *attempt* to reduce the amount of preemption of the hot thread. If the "hot" thread can be identified, you could do something like:

```
pthread_t thread = pthread_self();

//Set max prio, FIFO
struct sched_param params;
params.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);

int rv = pthread_setschedparam(thread, SCHED_FIFO, &params);
if(rv != 0){
  //Print error
  //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Spinlock might work better in your case. They avoid context switching and are highly efficient if the threads are likely to hold the lock only for short duration of time.

For this very reason, they are widely used in OS kernels.

Comment: the lock in question is *not* held only for short durations of time (the "high-contention" part in the question title).